# glob Images and sort by name not working above Number 10

Tags: php, sorting, glob

I have a really simple code with a problem I can't solve:

```
    $dirname = "some/directory";
    $images = glob($dirname."*.{png,jpg,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE);
    
    sort($images);
    
    foreach($images as $item){
        $title = explode('/', trim($item, '/'));
$fourth_segment = $title[3];
$title= str_replace([".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png"], "", $title[3]);
    echo '<h3>'.$title.'</h3><br /><img src="'.$item.'" style="width:500px;" /><br /><br />';
    }
```

This sorts my directory and posts its images in an sorted order on my webpage. Problem I have now is, that it is only working up to number 9.

My Directory:

- 1 01.01.2020.jpg
- 2 03.04.2020.jpg
- [3-8 following]
- 9 05.06.2020.jpg
- 10 08.07.2020.jpg

How it is sorted and shown by my code on the webpage:

- 1 01.01.2020.jpg
- 10 08.07.2020.jpg
- 2 03.04.2020.jpg
- [3-8 following]
- 9 05.06.2020.jpg

So its sorting as it should up to Number 9, but I don't get behind why the 10 is following the 1 and how I can solve this.

Does someone have an idea?

best regards

Comment: Add the `SORT_NATURAL` flag: `sort($images, SORT_NATURAL);` and see if that works better.

Comment: This actually sovles the problem! Can you post it as an answer and explain a little bit why this helps? I will mark it as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seem the sort is being done in an Alphabetic way. In Alphabetic sort, it makes sense for the 10 to appear before 9. In the same way it makes sense to "BA" appears before "I" for words sorted alphabetic. (0 = A, 1 = B, I = 9).

[According to the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php), the sort funcion accepts a flag parameter to modify the sorting behaviour. You can try to use the sort function like this:

```
sort($images, SORT_NATURAL);
```

Comment: Since the names aren't numerics (there's spaces in there and multiple dots + file extension), it makes more sense to use `SORT_NATURAL`.

Comment: SORT_NUMERIC doesn't work. SORT_NATURAL solved it. But thank you for your approach.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering myself what would happen with the non numeric characters when sorted numeric. I updated que answer accordingly.